# Exibir imagem no Excel através do código binário

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-excel, stored-procedures

Tenho um relatório em `Excel` onde os dados são exibidos através de uma `stored procedure`.

Estou com um problema pois quando eu busco o valor do campo imagem que é `blob`, ele exibe no relatório o código binário ao invés da imagem.

Como faço para o `Excel` ler o binário da consulta na `stored procedure` e exibir a imagem?

O banco é `SQL Server`.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Load-images-and-other-Binary-typed-data-into-the-Data-Model-23e61a1b-0ced-40b3-b1a2-1aed99d4d689

Comment: Caso não esteja usando o powerpivot como o @mauhumor citou, veja estes links: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/258038 - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308042 - http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/reading-and-writing-binary-files-visual-basic com certeza encontrará sua resposta. Não postei como resposta, pois, no momento, não tenho como testar... espero ter ajudado.